# Mapping array to array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I got an array of objects like this:

```
const defaultActors = 
[
  {
   data: {name: "name1"}
  },
  {
   data: {name: "name2"}
  }
]
```

and a simple array like this:

```
   const actorsToBeAdded = ["nameX", "nameY"]
```

Is there an easy way to get this:

```
 const combinedActors =  [
      {
       data: {name: "name1"}
      },
      {
       data: {name: "name2"}
      },
      {
       data: {name: "nameX"} //newly added
      },
      {
       data: {name: "nameY"} //newly added
      }
    ]
```

I'm using `useState` and trying to get combined array of objects like this:

```
    setCombinedActors(
    actorsToBeAdded.map((actor) => 
      ({
        data: {name : actor} //data from [nameX, nameY] array
        //also need to spread data from {name: "name1" ...} array
       })
     )
   )
```

EDIT: thanks for answers. Concat does result in one array but it's array of both "direct" values and objects, like this

```
["name1", "name2", {Object_with_data},{Object_with_data}]
```

is there a way to get

```
[{Object_with_data},{Object_with_data}, {Object_with_data},{Object_with_data}]
```

or this

```
["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
```

?
I created sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-taussig-zeyev?file=/src/App.js

Thanks to anyone interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concat both arrays using [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like:

```js
setCombinedActors(
    defaultActors.concat(
        actorsToBeAdded.map(actor => ({ data: { name : actor } }))
    )    
)
```

Also you may want to add only the actors that are still not in the `defaultActors` array, for that you can use a filter like:

```js
setCombinedActors(
    defaultActors.concat(
        actorsToBeAdded
            .filter(actor => !defaultActors.some(({ data }) => data.name === actor))
            .map(actor => ({ data: { name : actor } }))
    )    
)
```

Answering the edit, if you want to conver all to `String`'s.

```js
arr.map(elm => typeof elm === 'string' ? elm : elm.data.name)
```

Otherwise, if you want objects.

```js
arr.map(elm => typeof elm === 'string' ? { data: { name: elm } } : elm)
```

Note: Assuming all elements of the array are either a `String` or an object with the structure `{ data: { name: 'a string' } }`.

Comment: So you have an array with either objects or strings and you want to make it only strings or objects right?

Comment: Check edit to see if that was it. Just a reminder don't post multiple questions in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

```
actorsToBeAdded.forEach(value=>{
defaultActors.push(
              {data:{name:value}},
              );
}
)
```

Try this out.